# openlayers 6, показать информацию о нескольких объектах векторного слоя

Tags: javascript, openlayers

У меня есть карта с тайловым слоем, в которой объекты могут накладываться друг на друга. Прикладываю код, который показывает информацию, если кликнуть на точку, но он не работает если объекты накладываются, например если в точке пересекаются несколько объектов. Функция показывает информацию об объекте, который идет первым в таблице, остальные игнорирует. Вопрос, как исправить код. Чтение документации о TileLayer и об getFeatureInfoUrl не помогло.
Пытался использовать векторный слой и в нем можно итерировать через все объекты в точке, можно ли сделать то же самое в тайловом слое?

```js
function infoShow(src, tag1) {
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById(tag1).innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = src.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate,
      viewResolution,
      'EPSG:3857', {
        'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
      }
    );
    if (url) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(html) {
          document.getElementById(tag1).innerHTML = html;
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил что на русском - поправил